# adding elements to arrayCollection gets disorder

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

Whenever I add the sorted list(which is coming from the server side) into the arrayCollection it gets disorder, and no sorted list is viewed on the flex GUI. Can any one tell why is this happening how we may resolve it ?

Comment: It should not happen, unless you have Sort assigned to the array collection on the UI.

Answer (score 0):

The sorting that was applied to the list might be get nulled when applied as the source of the ArrayCollection.

Regardless of how it is happening, you could create a Sort and apply it to the ArrayCollection after it has been created. But maybe you are trying to avoid that?